# How did Herman and Ernst know how many Tiger tanks were produced?

Tags: historical-context, serhiy-zhadan, ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad

The following dialog occurred in *Voroshilovgrada*:

> "Herman, you're a history buff, right?"
> "Sure."
> "Then you probably know how many Tigers were produced in the Reich?"
> "What model are we talking about?"
> "All the models put together."
> "Around fifteen hundred."
> "Well, thirteen hundred fifty-five, to be exact," Ernst said jubilantly.

How did they know such precise figures?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: This is a _literature_ question?

Comment: @kimchilover Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Presumably a history buff would have read it in a history book?

Comment: They have the Internet. Such a figure is readily locatable; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_I

Comment: @Valorum Good point - I didn't realize that such an exact figure was so readily available. That could probably be the answer.